# UserControl that will notify viewmodel if user clicks anywhere outside of of it or it becomes no longer visible

Tags: xaml, mvvm, winrt-xaml

I have an element that is connected to a viewmodel that uses MediaCapture to record audio. If the user is recording audio(presses the record button), and then navigates away from it (clicks somewhere else in the UI, switches windows etc...), I would like to stop the recording in my viewmodel.

I would like to be able to bind a dependency property on an element that will notify my viewmodel if the user clicks anywhere outside of the element or it becomes no longer visible to the user).

Is there and event inside a custom usercontrol that I can connect to a DP that will report what I'm looking for?

Comment: Bind the IsFocused property to a bool in your ViewModel and act on this value changing?

Comment: @LeeO. I don't think that IsFocused exists for WinRT elements

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for page changes  you can  override the OnNavigatedFrom method of the page get the view model via
var viewModel = LayoutRoot.DataContext as MyViewModelType;

And then invoke your stop record method on viewModel ciewModel.StopRecording ()

For tapping other control or the recording control being moved off screen due to scrolling ..
I would implement and event aggregator which was known by pages and ui elements so any event they respond to (tap /scroll) that you wish to use as a trigger for making the recording stop would publish a "StopRecordingEvent" that your view model could subscribe and listen to the event aggregator for.
http://developingzack.blogspot.com/2012/09/what-why-and-how-event-aggregator.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to find a solution that will allow the control to manage this on its own, the recording feature is in no way the primary purpose of the app and I am trying to avoid a situation where any time a new feature is added the person adding it will have to think about the event aggregator for recording